# Formatting value label to fit without being cut off

Tags: jquery, jquery-knob

I've got an issue where i'm  automatically formatting my [`jQuery.Knob`](https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob) instance and it's being cut off incorrectly. It ends up looking like this:

[image: jQuery Knob being cut off] [image] etc....

This slider just goes up in range (*max will be around `$10,000,000`, potentially more*), so you can understand that a larger portion of the displayed value will be cut off as it grows, which isn't what I want....

I managed to counter-act that with overloading the `draw` method, applying the following, but this isn't a full-proof method of doing so as the font size grows:

```
$(this.i).css('font-size', '90%').val('$' + parseFloat(this.cv, 10).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,").toString());
```

**But, I'd like a cleaner method without having to apply my own CSS to the presented label.**

I did try through the `format` with the following, but it's overloading:

```
format: function (value) {
    return '$' + parseFloat(value, 10).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,")
},
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/3c4d7L53/)

---

<sup>*I am using Bootstrap if that has anything to do with it, and the HTML for this container looks like this below:*</sup>

```
<div class='row margin-top-45'>
    <div class='col-lg-4'>
        <input value="50000" class="dial" data-step="5000" data-min="0" data-max="10000000" data-thickness="0.2" data-fgColor="#16A085" data-skin="tron">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you having trouble with your "knob"  overloading ?

Comment: @adeneo My "knob" just isn't playing ball today! (*ps, thanks, you made my day !*)

Comment: Are you need to automatically fit the text based on its size ? (without your own formatting)

Comment: I recommend reducing font dynamically based on the number of digits being display or switching to ($100k) format to fit everything inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my example of dynamically changing the font if you decide to go with this solution: https://jsfiddle.net/3c4d7L53/3/ Try changing the value from `xxxxx.xx` to `xxxxxx.xx` and you'll notice font reduce itself. From here you decide what the font value will be based on the number of digits you have to display using basic math.

Code itself is below. I kept your overloaded `format` function and added `change` function:

```js
jQuery('.dial').knob({
  format: function(e) {
    return '$' + parseFloat(e, 10).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,")
  },
  change: function(v) {
    var v = parseInt(v);
    var valLength = String(v).length;
    var defaultFontSize = 22;

    if (valLength > 5) {
      var defaultFontSize = 22 - ((valLength - 5) * 4);
      this.i.css({
        font: 'bold ' + defaultFontSize + 'px Arial'
      });
    } else {
      this.i.css({
        font: 'bold ' + defaultFontSize + 'px Arial'
      });
    }

  }
});
```